# No matching version found for vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 | Node issues after Shopware 6.5 Update

Tags: node.js, shopware, shopware6

I have updated my shop from Shopware 6.4 to 6.5 and everything seems to be working fine.

When I try to run `bin/build.sh` I am getting the following error:

`No matching version found for vue-template-compiler@2.6.14`

This affects build-storefront.sh and build-administration.sh.

I am using Node 18. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vue-template-compiler` has a version 2.6.14. You can see it on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler/v/2.6.14

I guess it is wrong caching behavior in your npm instance. You can try the following:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
```

Then it should be able to find the correct version.